# How do I test a Google Pay Class that's in Draft?

Tags: google-pay

I want to test a Google Pay LoyaltyClass as a "Draft" before I set it to "Under review".

When I try to invoke the [API to generate a LoyaltyObject](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/loyaltyobject/insert) I recieve the following error:

> Wallet Object Class {classId} not approved

Is it possible to test a Pass object before sending it for Google to review?

Comment: The docs suggest "Unreviewed classes aren't visible to the public, only to trusted testers". How do I add myself as a trusted tester?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue with setting the loyalty class to under review.

Answer (score 0):

You can add yourself as a trusted tester by clicking on the **Share account** button on the left menu of the issuer page: `https://pay.google.com/gp/m/issuer/{issuerId}` (replace `issuerId` with your actual issuer id).

[image: left hand menu]

Comment: There isn't an option saying "trusted tester". The only two available are view and edit. There's also owner option, but it's muted... Can you help me with that please?

Comment: I should have been more explicit. To add someone as a trusted tester, I think you need give the user view permission.